# What is inside /var/lib/nginx/body, it's size is more than 40GBs for me and it keeps on increasing

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu

On my development server, nginx is taking more than 40 GB for some random name files. These files are stored in `/var/lib/nginx/body` and I am unsure if I should delete these files. If I delete them, will there be some problem or will it be fine?

These will still keep on creating in the future. How can I stop this, or if I can delete them automatically if they are not in use or old files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search hints that `/var/lib/nginx/body` might be related   to the nginx http proxy module, which can use a local directory (tree) for storing temporary caches and buffers. The "random" file names are then MD5 hashes of cache keys and you might see a multilevel directory tree with directory names derived from the file name:  `./`**`c`**`/`**`29`**`/b7f54b2df7773722d382f4809d650`**`29c`**.

You should check your nginx configuration  if that `/var/lib/nginx/body` directory is specified there, although if it isn't it might be a default directory for a feature that was set when nginx was compiled .

See for example the [`proxy_store`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_store), the [`proxy_cache`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache)   , the [`proxy_cache_path`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path) and/or the related  [`proxy_temp_path`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_temp_path) directives.

You can tune the size of of that cache directory with different optional parameters:

> The special “cache manager” process monitors the maximum cache size set by the `max_size` parameter, and the minimum amount of free space set by the `min_free` (1.19.1) parameter on the file system with cache. When the size is exceeded or there is not enough free space, it removes the least recently used data.

It should be safe to delete such cache files and restart nginx

Comment: How can I clean out the complete folder, or should I delete the folder?

Comment: Again, inspect your configuration and first determine if there are explicit or implied directives that are the cause of all these stored files. Adjust if necessary.  If your configuration then still requires the parent directory  I expect that nginx will fail to restart when you completely delete it. The multi level directory structure  below the parent will be recreated as needed so it should be safe to delete all contents of the parent directory.

Comment: I did delete the files and restart the server, it did not cause any issue and the server storage also got free from a large number.

Answer (score 0):

You should find out what's in them for safety sake.
Use `head -n 32 <FILE>` to see the top few lines or  `tail -n 32 <FILE>` for the bottom, so you can determine if they are useful or not